# Need Help to process unstructed text file data

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have data which is RDD[String] and looks as below:

```
          T key:   STATE:A     Company:x                                                      
                   Line :90    SUBLINE:90
                   Type:A      ver:1.0
```

Expecting data like below

T Key  :    STATE :A   C0mpany:x  Line:90   SUBline :90   Type:A   Version:1.0

Basically want to merge data of T key and create column for T key of Struct Type.

Could you pls help.

Comment: sample data you have shared is in single line or multiple line in the RDD?

Comment: @BalajiReddy It is in multiple lines